# Losing EditText style after adding Views programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, viewflipper

I have a layout called wizard that has an empty ViewFlipper inside of it.

I have other views that include this 'wizard' and programmatically add children to the ViewFlipper inside the wizard. The problem I'm having is that one of these children has an EditText, and this View loses it's default style. I tried setting everything up in the xml file and the problem dissapeared, so the problem is in adding the views programmatically. I Also tried calling invalidate() on the main container (in the code below: `@+id/recarga_celular_main`), but nothing happens.
The Edit text can be seen in the following link: [EditText weird style problem](http://i42.tinypic.com/35cn15g.png)

The view is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recarga_celular_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/theme_home_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top" >
...

    <CustomWizard
        android:id="@+id/recargaCelular_wizard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/theme_layer_blue_bottom_black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"  >


    </CustomWizard>
...

</RelativeLayout>
```

The 'wizard' is something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/touch_wizard_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

...

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/wizard_flipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/aceptar_limpiar_btns"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
...

</LinearLayout>
```

In the java code, first I add the view to the flipper, and then I display the desired child:

```java
flipper.addView(step.getView(), flipper.getChildCount() - 1);
...
flipper.setDisplayedChild(index);
```

**EDIT**

Manually set the default EditText style:

```
<EditText
 style="@style/some_style"
 android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text" 
 android:gravity="left"
 android:hint="Celular" />
```

Comment: And by losing its style you're referring to a custom theme that you've set up?

Comment: No, I mean losing the default EditText style (borders, background...). See the picture in the [link](http://i42.tinypic.com/35cn15g.png). There is a TextView with the text **CELULAR** and next to it (horizontally) there is the EditText with hint **Celular**. As you can see, it has no background, no borders, noting.

Comment: Finally solved this explicitly setting the style in the EditText. Edited the question with a 'solution' in case someone happens to have the same problem.